# Users of GSAT-6A or similar communication satellites

Tags: communication-satellite, isro

Who are the actual users of the recently launched GSAT-6A(or similar communication satellites). Are these satellites only for millitary communication(using satellite phones)? I have a suspicion that it might be assisting our regular mobile phone(cell phone) communication as well but I don't know how because mobile phones use mobile towers(eNodeB in case of LTE) to communicate. Also, how can a civilian get access to the satellite phones which use such satellites?

Comment: Satphones use for example the Iridium constellation which is in much lower orbit (iirc this sat went to GTO so will be operating at Geostationary orbit - much higher latency).

Answer (score 1):

GSAT-6A has 6m antenna that allows to receive low power signals from handheld devices, thus allowing two way communication.

In 2005 the Antrix signed contract with bangalore based devas multimedia to lease 90% of S-BAND transponders for 12 years to it. But subsequently S-band being scarce the deal was terminated with reason being that military needs should be met first. [The controversy](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/antrix-devas-deal-case-madhavan-nair-ex-isro-chief-granted-bail/article22265703.ece)

Therefore, the main user shall be only security personnel in remote areas.

However, DRDO is still perfecting and tuning its handheld device used for such communication. [Info link](https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.india.com/news/india/gsat-6a-communication-satellite-will-help-armed-forces-personnel-here-is-how-2971054/amp/)